# AD737 or LTC1966 and DC+AC signal

Tags: rms

I have an input signal that is the sum of a DC and AC component. Lets say DC = +2.5V and AC = +-2.5 MAX (it can vary with time), 50Hz.

I know that I can implement a high pass filter with a simple RC network (maybe just enough with a Capacitor in series) but I wonder what could I get from an AD737 if I just use a passive resistor divider to move the 0-5V input range to 0-200mv required by AD737.

Could I, with this configuration, ignore the double supply requirement of AD737 and just connect VS- to ground?.

What about the LTC1966?.

PS: Input is a hall linear sensor measuring mains current.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The LTC1966 can operate single supply and has a modified differential input. I'm using an ACS711 for an audio power meter, but any hall sensor will do. Bias IN2 at the DC level to subtract and capacitively couple to IN1.